# How to tell $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits

There is a test to check if $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists. One needs to check to see if both right limit and left limit is same.

As there is no right limit when $x \to \infty$ the above test would be not useful. Is there any other test to confirm one is not calculating non existent limit to, e.g. say a function that keeps oscillating is there a test?

Comment: If $f$ is bounded and monotonic then limit exists

Comment: What if it is not known? When can we say limit does not exist?

Comment: Checking if the left and right limit are equal is not a useful test, because you still have to compute those limits !

Comment: @YvesDaoust I wouldn't say "not useful" though :)

Comment: @VIVID: you do understand what I mean: it is not useful to compute a limit.

Comment: You can use various facts , such as L'hopital's rule ( if applicable), also you can use a well known fact to give counterexamples :$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists( $a$ can be $\pm \infty$) iff $\forall$ sequences (in domain )$x_n\neq a$ and $x_n\to a$ , $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$ exists and is same for all sequences. or check whther the function is bounded or not  etc.

Comment: For example $\sin x$ is oscillatory so we guess limit at infinity doesn't exist, consider two sequences $x_n=2n\pi$, $y_n=(4n+1)\pi/2$ then $f(x_n)=0, f(y_n)=1$ so limit doesn't exist. If $f=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ then you can use L'hospital's rule or see that the function is unbounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to show it.

1. Compute the limit itself by using some tricks, L'Hopital, etc. (but I don't think it will help you)
2. Cauchy's(epsilon-delta) definition:

$$
\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} f(x)=a \iff \forall \space \varepsilon >0 \space \exists \space \delta>0: \space \space x > \frac{1}{\delta} \implies |f(x)-a|< \varepsilon
$$

3. Heine's definition:
   $$
   \lim_\limits{x \to \infty} f(x)=a \iff \text{ for every sequence $x_n$ s.t. $x_n$ converges to $\infty$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $a$ }
   $$

Actually the Cauchy's is useful to show the existence of limit. But the Heine's is more useful(in my experience) proving that limit doesn't exist(just take to sequences $x_n'$ and $x_n''$ that converge to infinity and show that sequences $f(x_n')$ and $f(x_n'')$ converge to different points).

But you should always understand that the actual way to solve any math problem **depends on the problem itself**. Maybe, for your case what I've described won't be useful. The whole math is such a thing that there always are lot's of shortcuts, you just need to recognize them.